# rails pagination without offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pagination, offset

We have build pagination

```
User.paginate(:per_page => 100, :page => params[:page]).where(username: 'abcd')
```

AS we know offset of higher value become slow so without offset how can I do it in Rails

so it will generate s

```
select * from users where username = 'abcd' limit 100 offset 200000
```

and it become slow

I have id field as uuid

AS I found I can make fast by

```
select * from users where id > [uuid of huge value] and username = 'abcd' limit 1000
```

1) How can I achieve it using rails paginate
2)

Comment: 1) There are no "Rails pagination". You should search for gem, which allow "infinity scroll" or implement it manually - very easy. 2) Do you really use comparison of raw uuids `id > last_max_uuid` ?

Comment: No uuid > last_maxuuid not giving exact array it giving some other values as well means Then I need to do like `select * from users where id > [uuid of huge value] and username = 'abcd' limit 1000` will it give the proper/coorect users result in faster ??

Comment: UUID id is not like int id baseed on `sequence`. Also I don't see any ordering and pagination can't work right without it.

Comment: okk adding one column for cid which would be in sequence...then will try..might work